# How to let an input form have multiple outputs?

Tags: javascript, forms, input, output

I am trying to make a form that someone can enter a number and each number entered will correspond to a certain value in the output text. What I have so far is this:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
   var x, text;
   x = document.getElementById("zip").value;

   if (x = 53527) {
      text = "$20.00";
   }
   if (x = 53718) {
      text = "$25.00";
   } 
   else {
      text = "Please Call for Delivery";
   }

   document.getElementById("fee").innerHTML = text;
}

</script>
```

Overall it works, but the problem that I am having is once a number is entered, it always displays the "$25.00" value no matter what is entered in. I am not sure what is making it override the other values. Any help would be great. I am new to this and learning it as I go.

Comment: kfb1991 did you find your way? Can I help you in some other way? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be working. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the single equal signs on **(x = 53527)** and **(x = 53718)** to double equal, i.e. **(x == 53527)** and **(x == 53718)** and see if works. Because in javascript when you are comparing values inside an **if** you have to have double equal.

Pay additional attention with your **else** clause because this is acting only over your second **if**. If you want to use it as an **else** for both **if**s you can use **else if** on your second if.

Comment: Exactly, and that's why I learned long ago to reverse the arguments in these comparisons.  i.e.  if (53527 === x)